# Запятая и тире в простом предложении с однородными членами

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

Сокол мал, [-] да удал.  Богат - [,] да крив, беден - [,] да прям.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Сокол мал, да (=но) удал.**

2) Два варианта: **(1) Богат, да крив; беден, да прям. (2) Богат ― да крив, беден ― да прям.**

Использование  тире или точки с запятой связано с необходимостью **обозначить структуру предложения** (БСП), что сложно сделать с помощью одних запятых.

Интонация соответствующая: точка с запятой обозначает понижение тона, тире ― восходяще-нисходящую интонацию, характерную для противопоставления

**Сравнить:** Между однородными членами ставится тире для выражения противопоставления (при пропуске противительных союзов «а», «но», «да», «зато», «однако», «хотя» и др.): Здесь не житье им — рай; Не любви прошу — жалости! **Однако в приведенном примере тире ставится и при наличии противительного союза**.

Comment: Зачем точка с запятой, если есть тире?

Comment: Конечно, не нужна. Текст исправлен.